# How adding Foundation icons using SASS in Foundation Email

Tags: css, node.js, email, zurb-foundation

i am using foundation zerb for Email and i want to use Foundation icons in my Project. I am new in scss and i tried to follow the instructions from the following [site](http://zurb.com/university/lessons/add-icon-fonts-to-give-your-product-some-polish) but i dont get it runing properly.

I created a font folder in my root directory (outside src) and i added the following code as discribed in my app.scss file:

```
enter code here
$font-path: "../fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons";
@font-face {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  src: url("#{$font-path}.eot");
  src: url("#{$font-path}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("#{$font-path}.woff") format("woff"),
       url("#{$font-path}.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("#{$font-path}.svg#fontcustom") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@import "../fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css";
```

In my Page i added for testing one icon but it didn't render the icon.

```html
<i class="fi-social-linkedin">linkedIn</i>
```

When i run the command **npm run build** i get the following error from the task runner gulp:

**Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\aro\aro_dev\emailfound\dist\font\foundation-icons\foundation-icons.css'
    at Error (native)
[00:11:11] The following tasks did not complete: default, build, inline
[00:11:11] Did you forget to signal async completion?**

Can someone help me?

Best Regards

Aro

Comment: The error means that your `@import "../fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css";` path is wrong; you do not have a file called `foundation-icons.css` in C:\Users\aro\aro_dev\emailfound\dist\font\foundation-icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the **scss** version of **foundation-email** do not include icon fonts , as icon fonts are not supported in most of email clients.

But if you have added your own icon fonts, or imported the foundation fonts from **foundation-sites** change your `$font-path:` variable to point to the correct path of fonts relative to you css file.

Instead of using icon fonts use png or jpg images for your icons.

Comment: Thank you! I will use png or jpg images to get them work in my Email.